How can i implement common new Window Component in Angular 15?
I'm using Angular 15.
I want to create a new common window component. For example:
 <div
  class="detail-icon-container"
  (click)="windowComponent.openNewWindow()"
  ></div>
...
<pop-up-window #windowComponent>
  <div WindowContent>
    <div>plz show me the contents...</div>
  </div>
</pop-up-window>

and when the user presses a certain button, I want the something-content component to appear in a new window.
But when I get to the window, I don't see my component in the new window. Also, ComponentFactoryResolver is deprecated, so I'm not sure how to implement it.
I want a common component that can launch a new window, and that will display the component that each user injects as content in a new window pane.
pop-up-window.component.html
<ng-template class="popup-content-container">
  <ng-content #WindowContent></ng-content>
</ng-template>


pop-up-window.component.ts
import {
  ApplicationRef,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  EmbeddedViewRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pop-up-window',
  templateUrl: './pop-up-window.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pop-up-window.component.scss'],
})
export class PopUpWindowComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('WindowComponent') windowComponent!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('WindowContent', { static: true, read: ElementRef })
  popupContent!: ElementRef;
  @Input() windowWidth!: number;
  @Input() windowHeight!: number;
  @Input() windowLeft!: number;
  @Input() windowTop!: number;
  @Input() windowTitle!: string;
  @Input() windowStyle!: string;
  @Input() windowStyleUrl!: string;
  @Input() suppressCloneStyles = false;
  @Output() closed: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  private popupWindow!: Window | null;
  private observer!: MutationObserver;

  constructor(
    private applicationRef: ApplicationRef,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.popupContent);
  }

  @HostListener('beforeunload')
  beforeunloadHandler() {
    this.close();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.observer?.disconnect();
    this.close();
  }

  close() {
    if (this.popupWindow) {
      this.popupWindow.close();
      this.popupWindow = null;
      this.closed.next(true);
    }
  }

  openNewWindow(): Window | null {
    const elmRect =
      this.viewContainerRef?.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const navHeight = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const navWidth = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth;
    const winLeft = this.windowLeft || window.screenX + navWidth + elmRect.left;
    const winTop =
      this.windowTop || window.screenY + navHeight + elmRect.top - 60;
    this.popupWindow = window.open(
      '',
      '',
      `width=${this.windowWidth},
    height=${this.windowHeight},
    left=${winLeft},
    top=${winTop}`
    );

    if (!this.popupWindow) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log(this.popupContent);

    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      this.popupContent.nativeElement
    );

    this.applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    const newWindowContainerElement = this.popupWindow.document.createElement(
      'app-new-window-container'
    );
    this.popupWindow.document.body.appendChild(newWindowContainerElement);

    const componentRootNode = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
    newWindowContainerElement.appendChild(componentRootNode);

    return this.popupWindow;
  }
}



please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working stackblitz with the issue reproduced, also update the stackblitz code on the question!

Thank you for your response. I've updated the code as you said!
